# Detect ng-content changes dynamically

Tags: angular

I have a situation where I'd like to detect in a component whether an `<ng-content>` element inside it's template gets populated with anything dynamically.

So consider this markup in a component

```
<div class="ald-layout__wrapper" [class.ald-layout__wrapper--has-side-panel]="sidebarPresent">
        <!-- CONTENT SLOT -->
        <ng-content select="ald-content"></ng-content>
        <!-- SIDE PANEL SLOT -->
        <ng-content select="ald-side-panel"></ng-content>
    </div>
```

Example usage for this component usage:

```
<ald-layout>
    <ald-content>
        Content here...
    </ald-content>
    <ald-side-panel *ngIf="showSidePanel">
        Side panel content
    </ald-side-panel>
</ald-layout>
```

I want to be able to detect in the `ald-layout` component when `ald-side-panel` is present in the DOM.

I wondered about using a service to track the visibility\presence state of the side panel, but wondering if there is a better pattern\approach to use here?

Comment: I would go with a service as @Output events in Angular do not propagate past the boundary of their parent.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `@ContentChildren` you'll get a property/collection of type `QueryList`. You can listen for changes in the content children list by subscribing to it's [changes](https://angular.io/api/core/QueryList#properties) property

Something like

```js
@ContentChildren() cc: QueryList<Type>;

ngOnInit() {
    this.cc.changes.subscribe(v => {
        ....
    }
}
```